# Why Artisan::queue is blocking code execution?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-artisan

I am having `Artisan::queue` in my controller and after queuing, I will `return redirect()->back()`. However, when I call this function from frontend, the webpage will just stuck at loading, never reach the `return` statement

Using default `sync` driver

Comment: What queue driver are you using?

Comment: you would need to provide more details ... what queue driver are you using?

Comment: default sync driver

Comment: well `sync` is synchronous it is not asynchronous; so it is working as expected presumably (running the code synchronously instead of asynchronously) ... if you want it to be asynchronous you would have to use a different queue driver

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @lagbox, `sync` is not asynchronous. Problem is solved by using `database` driver.